# Estimation of mean of ratio of empirical distributions

Tags: estimation, ratio

I am trying to estimate the mean of the ratio of two empirical count distributions $f(x)$ and $b(x)$ defined on the limited range $[-1, 1]$

$$
\left<\frac{f(x)}{b(x)}\right>
$$

$f(x)$ and $b(x)$ are measured in a counting experiment by filling unweighted histograms which then have Poisson uncertainties in each bin. To naively calculate the mean I can choose a binning for the histograms which is coarse enough that bins have enough counts to estimate the ratio and its uncertainty (e.g. more than zero counts in $b$) and calculate the ratio in each bin in $x$ and then average over the full $x$ range in the resulting ratio histogram. At the same time using a coarser binning means that I lose resolution when extracting the mean.

Are there other possible ways to estimate this mean which allow me to avoid rebinning just to keep $b$ from ever being 0? Computing power isn't an issue so iterative approaches are perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you calculating the expected ratio as a function of the bin or across all bins?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: I am looking for the mean over the full $x$ range [-1,1].

Comment: Ok, I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to calculate. It seems like you are tring to estimate the following limit: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{N_{f(x_{i+1}-x_i)}}{N_{g(x_{i+1}-x_i)}}$ Where $N_{a(i)}$ is the number of counts in bin i for the random variable with distribution a.

Comment: If what you want is the mean of the ratio of two variables *defined* by their empirical distribution, then you can do that simply by resampling from each empirical distribution, forming the ratio and then getting the average ratio over many simulation iterations. If your goal is more general, in that you have random empirical distributions with poisson binning, then you need a two-phase Monte Carlo: Phase 1: generate distribuitons given a binning, Phase II: generate values from this distribution to form ratios and get average. Now, you average the average over many iteratios of Phase I.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: The issue with your suggestions is that they require good knowledge of the distributions. The problem is that I can only estimate them from incomplete data (e.g. have to rebin them to so that all counts in $b$ are $>0$ for sampling from them in some meaningful way).

Comment: Ah, I see. So you have a fixed sample but a random partition/binning (with the condition that each parition contains at least 1 data point) and then you want to calculate the average value of the ratio, *given* the random partition and repeat this across all possible bining arrangements?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: I am just interested in a robust estimator of the mean with good resolution. Of course its (central) value shouldn't depend on the binning.

Comment: I thought I understood, but now I'm not so sure. Could you add detail to your post, namely: how do you create f(x) and b(x)? Do you actually have data, or is this a hypothetical study? How is the poisson distribution used in your problem? If you knew f(x) and b(x) perfectly, would you want the expected value of the ratio of two variables F, B each following the associated distribution? Is there reason to believe that B can be zero? Finally, are the two variables correllated or independent?